# How to show frame rate and cpu stats on Far Cry 4

Tags: framerate, far-cry-4

How can I show frame rate and other stats in Far Cry 4?

Comment: CPU stats: ctrl + Shift + Esc. Frame rate: Using a third party software like FRAPS or MSI Afterburner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see the CPU usage of the game using Windows Task Manager <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd>.

You can also see your frame rate using a third party software such as FRAPS or MSI Afterburner.

Comment: hes referring to this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VuOM0rYXkgQ#t=26

Comment: I downloaded MSI Afterburner, mapped my hot keys to show FPS, but nothing displays in the game; does it have to be enabled before I launch the game?

Comment: [This 2 minutes YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xeUSkaZ4_t0) Should put you on the right track.
@Sickest This looks a lot like MSI Afterburner OSD. But someone might have released a FarCry4 benchmark tool/app too, I just didn't fint it anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `Documents\Games\Farcry 4\Profile.xml` and open it with a text editor.

Replace `show fps 0` with `show fps 1` and save the file.